force collapse_rows to not collapse rows in certain places
I am using collapse_rows() from the kableExtra package and it works a treat, and as expected.
But I would like some rows to not collapse in various situations.
Take this table, for instance:
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

EgTable <- array( dim = c(4, 4))

colnames(EgTable) <- c("Col 1",
                       "Col 2",
                       "Col 3",
                       "Col 4")
rownames(EgTable) <- c("Row 1",
                       "Row 2",
                       "Row 3",
                       "Row 4")

EgTable[1, ] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
EgTable[2, ] <- c("A", "b", "C", "D")
EgTable[3, ] <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
EgTable[4, ] <- c("A", "b", "C", "D")

knitr::kable(EgTable, format="latex") %>%
  kableExtra::collapse_rows()

This works fine, and does what is expected:

But what I would like, in some of my tables, is for a horizontal line separating Rows 1+2 and Rows 3+4 (i.e., a dividing line separating the first two from the last two rows, going the full width of the table)
These rows still would have A C and D in the cells in Columns 1, 3 and 4 respectively still... but collapsed only over Rows 1+2 and also over Rows 3+4.
(I hope that makes sense...)
So, I want this (thanks to some image editing):

I have read the help for collapse_rows and I cannot see how to make this work. Likewise, a web search hasn't been fruitful.
Any help appreciated.
P.

It seems I can use:
kableExtra::collapse_rows(latex_hline="full")

even though I do not understand the description of latex_hline in the help... Trial and error gave me the answer.
